# python - pyqt5 - QFileDialog - problem with greek characters in specified path

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog

In QFileDialog (pyqt5), there is a problem when the specified path has greek characters.

Example path: C:/Users/cpapp/OneDrive/Υπολογιστής -> select desktop

Problem:

[image]

I search in the web for the solution. It says to change some registry entries for desktop path. But i don't know what change should i apply, because the specified path may be correct.

Comment: That is an error from the native dialog, Qt has nothing to do with that. In any case, your description is vague: what are you trying to do? Open a file? Select a file to save? Access a directory? And what do you mean by "select desktop"? The native windows file dialog has many ways to access the desktop. Please be more detailed in your description.

Comment: I am trying to select a folder to save a file

Comment: You didn't answer the final question.